# SVN and Visual Studio Database Projects?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, database-project

What are the conventions for which files or file types to include in SVN for a Visual Studio Database Project (the equivalent of ignoring *.suo, *.csproj.user, etc)?

I'm just starting to play with using a DB project to manage the data side of a web app, and I notice that the connection string for deployment to a database is stored in the .dbproj file, which is otherwise universal and needs to be in SVN.  But in an ideal scenario, this setting should be per-developer, so that they can update and press Deploy and have everything in their development DB updated.  If this setting was in a user options file, then one could simply version only the necessary sql files.

Also, when you change the target deployment database, it creates a bunch of files in sql/debug or sql/release: $databasename_Database.sqlcmdvars, $databasename_Database.sqldeployment, $databasename_Database.sqlsettings, $databasename_Script.PostDeployment.sql, and $databasename_Script.PreDeployment.sql.  With the same logic as above, aren't those specific to my development database?

Another approach would be to point the project to a shared test DB server, but [that's been said to be a bad idea](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/30/three-rules-for-database-work.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

replace the hardcoded database name with an msbuild property e.g. - $(DatabaseName) You could add a default value of this into the dbproj but also supply different values via msbuild e.g.

```
msbuild your.dbproj /p:DatabaseName=YourDBServer
```